# How is error handling done in Retrofit 2 ? I can not find the RetrofitError class that most of the solutions suggest?

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to implement a error handling mechanism using Retorfit 2.

The solutions that are available are using RetrofitError class which I can't find in the current repo.

Comment: May be, Java default Error class should be used...

Comment: Look at this code https://github.com/ryee1/MovieProject/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/hfad/movieproject/RetainedFragment.java

Comment: Retrofit 2.0 is biggest update among all the vesions. check this link http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Answer (score 14):

If you are making synchronous request, you define your request method in the interface as `Call<List<Car>>`.

Once you execute the request you receive response and deserialized data wrapped in `Response<T>` as `Response<List<Car>>`. This wrapped gives you access to headers, http codes and raw response body.

You can access error body as:

```
 Call<List<Car>> carsCall = carInterface.loadCars();

   try {
      Response<List<Car>> carsResponse = carsCall.execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           //network Exception is throw here
        }
     if(carsResponse != null && !carsResponse.isSuccess() && carsReponse.errorBody() != null){
          // handle carsResponse.errorBody()
     }
```

For async calls, you receive `Throwable`, if I/O exception is thrown during the network call:

```
Call<List<Car>> call = service.loadCars();
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Car>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<List<Car>> response) {
        // Get result from response.body(), headers, status codes, etc
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
      //handle error 
    }
});
```

Comment: Please note that **`onResponse` is called even on failure, and `response.body()` will (supposedly) be null!**

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Indeed, the if statement that is mentioned in paragraph about sync calls, also applies to async calls.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Thank you so much for the answer. However, this is not what I was looking for. I wanted a generic error handler that Retrofit would call before it called its call back methods.

I worked around it by creating a wrapper method in one of my classes that basically takes a listener as an argument, and prepares a custom response/ error before invoking listener methods.

Answer (score 9):

```
Call<List<data>> call = MyService.loadData();
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<data>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<data>> call, Response<List<data>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            //Response success. Handle data here
        }
        else{
            //For getting error message
            Log.d("Error message",response.message());
            //For getting error code. Code is integer value like 200,404 etc
            Log.d("Error code",String.valueOf(response.code()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<data>> call, Throwable t) {
        if (t instanceof IOException){
            //Add your code for displaying no network connection error

        }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple method:

```
int code = response.raw().code();
String message = response.raw().message();
```