# retrofit2 abstraction network android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I use retrofit2 to handle the network of an Android app. I want to abstract the network, like I only do `netWorkManager.getsearch()` and it do the async request and UI update. All the tutoriels I've seen have, the code to update UI in the Callback on the @Override `onResponse` in the code of the activity to update the UI (and I want to handle that in my networkManager). I wanted to pass a function or a method to handle the return of the Callback but with my research I think it's not impossible. Am I missing something on the use of retrofit2 ? Did you have any ideas to solve my problem or how to do a good abstraction of the network in Android ?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not impossible, although it differs depending on whether you use the synchronous (`execute()`) or asynchronous (`enqueue()`) call.

As you know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32632956/2413303), this is how you handle them:

```
   Call<List<Car>> carsCall = carInterface.loadCars();
   try {
        Response<List<Car>> carsResponse = carsCall.execute();
   } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //network Exception is thrown here
   }
   if(carsResponse != null && !carsResponse.isSuccess() && carsReponse.errorBody() != null){
       // handle carsResponse.errorBody()
   }
```

For async calls:

```
Call<List<Car>> call = service.loadCars();
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Car>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<List<Car>> response) {
        // Get result from response.body(), headers, status codes, etc
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        //handle error 
    }
});
```

For a service defined like so

```
public interface RetrofitCarService {
    @GET("api/getCars")
    Call<List<Car>> getCars();
}
```

But if you'd want to abstract it, you could easily do something like this

```
public interface YourCallback<T> {
    void onSuccess(T t);
    void onError(Throwable throwable);
}

public interface CarService {
    void getCars(YourCallback<List<Car>> callback);
}

public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {
    private RetrofitCarService retrofitCarService;

    public CarServiceImpl(RetrofitCarService retrofitCarService) {
        this.retrofitCarService = retrofitCarService;
    }

    public void getCars(YourCallback<List<Car>> callback) {
        retrofitCarService.getCars().enqueue(new Callback<List<Car>>() { 
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<List<Car>> response) {
                callback.onSuccess(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                callback.onError(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you'd be abstracted away:

```
@Inject
CarService carService;

public void something() {
    carService.getCars(new YourCallback<List<Car>>() {
        public void onSuccess(List<Car> cars) {
            refreshDataSet(cars);
        }
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            showError(throwable);
        }
    });
}
```

Please note that this would however force your `Service` to only be async, which throws away the ability of `Call`s to represent both sync and async operations. If you think about a bit, you can however also abstract away `Call<T>`.